# JUnit Spring - HSQLDB doesn't close efter tests

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm using JUnit to test my Spring Services but I'm having problems closing the connection to my HSQLDB inbetween tests. I've set the destroy-method attribute in the bean to my datasource's close method but it still remains locked even when I close the container.

Odd thing is that this only happens in my JUnit test class and not in my client. On my client the container closes when I call it's close method.

I've also supplied an @AfterClass method in the JUnit test but that doesn't help either.

Any idea?

Comment: its likely that the persistence context is absent in the junit test . what runner are you using ( @RunWith annotation ) ? if its spring what context configuration are you loading for the test ? can you provide your code ?

Comment: I'm quite new to Spring and I'm following the Spring Fundamentals course on VirtualPairProgrammers. So I just know basic JUnit and basic Spring currently. The code works but the database just doesn't close inbetween tests which makes some of the tests a bit wonky. My datasource is dbcp and I use JDBC. If that's what you were asking for?

Comment: can you post or link the junit class in question ?

Answer (score 0):

What does your Junit test doing with HSQLDB for unit test? Is it adding new record into HSQLDB or any kind of update/delete that requires DB commit?
Check if you set HSQLDB's autocommit=false and doing DML operation, without commit or rollback.

Comment: It adds and deletes from the database. I also fetch data from the DB in some tests.

Comment: As I mentioned, check if you are running the operations with autocommit=false and you are not specifically call commit() operation in your unit test. If you are not sure if you are under autocommit or not.. just call commit() in every end of DB insert/update/delete ( or call commit() in the function where @After annotations is added ).